I want to connect my basic LG TV to Wi-Fi
I have a LG TV which does not have any smart features like connecting to WIFI or casting screen from my phone to my TV.
But it has an HDMI port and an USB port.
I want to play downloaded videos which are present in my phone and laptop to my TV and also I don't want my phone to always stay connected to my TV.
What I  am thinking is a pluggable device which can be plugged into my TV and connected to my phone or laptop over WIFI. Said device should have some form of external storage support, And from my phone or laptop, I can copy and delete media files to that device storage wirelessly.
My devices are

Android

Linux Mint

LG 22LB452A


I have a little bit of programming knowledge if that may be necessary in setup.
In my research I came to know about miracast devices like chromecast and EZCast but I don't need the ability to play youtube or such streaming services. My family will always be on TV if that happens.
What should I buy? preferably cheaper? lastly sorry for my little knowledge.

The main current competitors are ChromeCast, FireStick, and Roku. I would NOT recommend a "smart" TV, as you have no way to upgrade it in the future. I have worked with multiple smart TVs that, as they have aged, have become so unresponsive that the navigating the menu to do even normal operations like changing the input, is nearly impossible. Built in processors are usually cheaper and having to do more jobs. It's also MUCH easier to upgrade a dumb TV to the latest version of FireStick or swap to ChromeCast instead of buying whole new TV every few years. All 3 can do what you are looking for in various ways.
Your alternatives are to use a Media PC or a NAS that can double as a Media PC, but that is a much bigger topic than can be explained here.
Plex is the biggest name software in organizing and streaming your locally stored media files, but again, that's a big topic.
Personally, I would install a Plex server on your laptop and buy a FireStick.
If you want to explicitly avoid the name brand streaming devices, then get a simple mini-PC and set up a simple SMB share you can push files to. Then you log into the mini-PC and run the file. It's a bit more tedious, but much more capable.

A virtually off the shelf solution would be to

Install a plex server on your computer or a Raspberry Pi with SD card storage.
Plug in an Amazon Firestick to your TV.
Install the plex app on the Firestick.

But seriously, you may be better off upgrading your TV. Generic Android ones are cheap.
